# array_map show mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

when i use

```
array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);

it display

    Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\xampp\htdocs\...\...\xyz.php on line 14
```

what is the reason after that?

**EDIT:**
 and if i use

```
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'mysql_real_escape_string');
```

then it display

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be resource, integer given in D:\xampp\htdocs\..\...\xyz.php on line 17
```

please also tell me the difference above both method?
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume that one of the elements of `$_POST` is indeed an array, visualised something like this:

```
print_r($_POST);

Array
(
 ...
    'element' => Array
    (
        'subelement' => 'some value'
    )
 ...
)
```

When `array_map` tries to give the value of `$_POST['element']` to `mysql_real_escape_string`, it throws the error you describe.

You could try to wrap the call though, something along this (untested) function:

```
function recursive_escape(&$value) {
    if (is_array($value))
        array_map('recursive_escape', $value);
    else
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

array_map('recursive_escape', $_POST);
```

Comment: Casey, I was just about to post this. Good answer.

Comment: @Cassy - Thank You Sir, one last query, after applying this function may  i use `$_post['variable']`  directly in mysql query or i need to save post array in another array via applying above function

Comment: Same problem here: If `$_POST['variable']` is an array, you still need to unwind it before you can pass it on to mysql. If it is a scalar (i.e. string or int) you can use it right away.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible that on of the values of your `$_POST` is an array?

Does your form look something like:

```
<input type="text" name="value[]">
```

or do any of the names have `[]` in them? That would cause an array to be in the `$_POST` data.

Try `var_dump`ing your `$_POST` and see if any of the values are arrays.

If it is an array, then you have a problem, as `mysql_real_escape_string` won't take an array as a parameter. In which case you would want to look at Cassy's function to do it recursively.

---

You may want to try reading the documentation to find the difference between the two functions:

In `array_walk_recursive`, the function its being passed to recieves a key as a second parameter, while array_map doesn't.

(PHP has a really great documentation. Use it.)

Comment: yes it have the array within array

Comment: Your answer is also good and helping.